# Middleman prepends "/" before js and css directory

Tags: ruby, middleman

Somehow my middleman build creates

```
<link href="/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/js/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(note the slash at the beginning of the links) while

```
<link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

would be correct.

How can I change that?

I use pretty much the standard build settings:

```
configure :build do
  activate :minify_css
  activate :minify_javascript
end
```

and the template sections looks like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'all' %>
```

Comment: So does Rails. Why do you consider a leading slash erroneous? It's just an absolute reference based on a folder structure assumption (convention over configuration and all)

Comment: I need to package the result as phonegap app, and the structure requires it that way.

Comment: Then I suggest to manually include them and avoid using the asset helpers.  Alternative you can define your own helpers which return exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `activate :relative_assets` to your `config.rb`.